# jQuery Validation with Multiple Error Placement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I have the following form inputs.

```
<div class="input-group">
     <input type="text" id="FirstName" name="FirstName">
     <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
       <div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" id="LastName" name="LastName">
       </div>
</div>
<div >
    <ul class="list-unstyled" id="LastNameErrors">

    </ul>
</div>
```

1) I want to place the error message for the `FirstName` below the input-group .

2) I want to place the error message for the `LastName` inside a `ul` which has an id of `#LastNameErrors`

I can achieve the firstname placement by doing the following but whats the jquery to achieve the error placement for the last name as per requirement above?

The following keeps appending to the `ul` and doesnt remove the error when the field is valid.

```
$("form").validate({
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            var placement = element.closest('.input-group');
            var firstNameError = true;

            if (!placement.get(0)) {
                firstNameError = false;
                placement = $("#LastNameErrors");
            }
            if (error.text() !== '') {

                if (firstNameError)
                    placement.after(error);
                else
                    placement.append('<li ><label>' + error.text() + '</li>');
            }
        }

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The following keeps appending to the ul and doesnt remove the error when the field is valid.

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    ....
    if (error.text() !== '') {
        if (firstNameError)
            ....
        else
            placement.append('<li ><label>' + error.text() + '</li>');
    }
    ....
```

- You do not need a conditional `if (error.text() !== '')` because `errorPlacement` does nothing when there is no error message.
- By default, the plugin creates the error message element and then replaces/toggles it dynamically.  Since you're only stripping the text from this object, `error.text()`, and creating your own element, the plugin cannot find/replace/toggle the message.  Therefore, you just keep appending a new error message on every instance.

Instead, you'll need to use the **entire** object called `error`.  Something more like this will work better because the plugin can find and replace/toggle the native error message element.  Adjust your code as needed.

```
$("#LastNameErrors li").append(error);
```

**DEMO**:  [jsfiddle.net/fLsyd7x8/](http://jsfiddle.net/fLsyd7x8/)

Comment: OP is adding li elements dynamically per error i suppose?

Comment: @TechBreak, using `errorPlacement`, this plugin will only display one error at a time for any particular field, so there will never be more than one `li` displayed.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite strange the way you are trying to achieve but in general you should have a generic mechanism to show the error messages.

However, to your problem you should check for the elements `id` to know who is problematic and then decide where to show the error messages,

```
    $("form").validate({
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {

                var elId = element.attr('id');
                if(elId == 'LastName')
                {
                   $('ul#LastNameErrors').append('<li ><label>' + error.text() + '</li>');
                }
                else
                if(elId == 'FirstName')
                {
                   var placement = element.closest('.input-group');
                   placement.append('<li ><label>' + error.text() + '</li>');
                }
                //else more your requirements....                
             }
        });
```

Make sure to clear any existing messages before adding new error messages otherwise it will keep on appending.

Comment: [Your answer does not solve the OP's complaint.  The message will still repeat.  See:  jsfiddle.net/s9515sxr/](http://jsfiddle.net/s9515sxr/)